# Show Image at selected position and hide all other previous images in recycler view

Tags: android

I'm displaying a list and I want to show the selected item by setting the visibility of an image view to visible but I'm having an issue keep tracking of the previous position. How Can I show the image view at selected position and hiding all the images at other positions after the user selects some element?

What I mean is that I've a layout with text views and images. What I want is that when I click on a position suppose 2. Then the image at that position should be visible and all other images should be hidden. Let's assume I've selected another position like 3 now I want to hide the image and index 2 and show the image at index 3.

```
  holder.tvId.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
  holder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
  
  if(model.getName().equals("Current Location")){
     holder.tvAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
  }else{
     holder.tvAddress.setText(model.getUserEnteredAddress());
  }
        
  holder.tvCityName.setText(model.getCity());
```

Comment: can you show what you have done in your adapter?

Comment: I've added some code. Kindly take a look

Comment: I tried setting the image based on the clicked id but it didn't gave me any response I was looking for.

Comment: Basically the image is placed to show which option is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in order to achieve what you expect. From what I can think of is you need to hide all the image then show only the image that you clicked

First, add a new getter & setter in your Model

```
public class Model
  {
    ...
    boolean isVisible = true;
    public String getIsVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }
  }
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder` function in your adapter, handle it like this

```
@Override  
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   ...
   if (!model.getIsVisible()) {
      ivMyImage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
   }

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           for (Model model : models) { 
              model.setIsVisible(false);
           }
           model.setIsVisible(true);
           ivMyImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just choose the selected position when you create the image view,then you can add all the images of your list in separate imageView and position them in the exact same postion and make all them invisible ,then depending on your clicked item you just set visibility to VIEW.visible ,for further answer you need to explain your question properly with more information

Comment: I've tried to explain it further. Kindly take a look